# How to set up permissions for Kubernetes resources?

Tags: kubernetes

First off, I'm aware of the [Kubernetes RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) method. My question is: is there a way to create Kubernetes resources that can only be read and/or written by a specific `Role` (or a `ClusterRole`)?

For example, let's say I have a Kubernetes `Secret`. I want this `Secret` to be bound to a specific `ClusterRole`, then only a `ServiceAccount` bound to this specific `ClusterRole` could read it. Is there a way to set up something like that?

**Edit**: it looks like what I want here is not possible. Kubernetes RBAC was designed to *GRANT* access to certain resources. I wanted to *DENY* access based on a specific group (or set of rules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the RBAC for managing the Role-based access in K8s

> For example, let's say I have a Kubernetes Secret. I want this Secret
> to be bound to a specific ClusterRole, so only a ServiceAccount bound
> to this specific ClusterRole could read it. Is there a way to set up
> something like that?

No, you can not use the `ClusterRole` for granular level access, however, you can create some `Role` to restrict **secret**.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: secret-read-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"] 
  resources: ["secret"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: secret-read-sa
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: secret-read-rolebinding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: secret-read-sa
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: secret-read-role
  apiGroup: ""
```

Checkout about the **resourceNames** you can also give a name or pattern in name so this way it might be helpful to attach a specific secret to **Role**.

```
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
  resourceNames: ["userA-*"]
```

If you planning to Go with **RBAC** you can use the `RBAC manager` for better management : https://github.com/FairwindsOps/rbac-manager

**Extra** :

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
namespace: data-engineering
name: umbrella:data-engineering-app
rules:
– apiGroups: [“”]
resources: [“configmaps”]
resourceNames:  [“data-engineering-app-configmap”]    <<<<<<<<<
verbs: [“get”]
—
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
name: umbrella:data-engineering-app
roleRef:
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
kind: Role
name: umbrella:data-engineering-app
subjects:
– kind: ServiceAccount
name: data-engineering-app
namespace: data-engineering
```

You can also refer to resources by name for certain requests through the **resourceNames** list. When specified, requests can be restricted to individual instances of a resource. Here is an example that restricts its subject to only get or update a `ConfigMap` named `my-configmap`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: configmap-updater
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing ConfigMap
  # objects is "configmaps"
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  resourceNames: ["my-configmap"]
  verbs: ["update", "get"]
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources

Good Example : https://thenewstack.io/three-realistic-approaches-to-kubernetes-rbac/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The whole problem in my case here is that RBAC in Kubernetes is designed to *GRANT* access to some resources. You have a ServiceAccount and you grant it access to resources. What I wanted is the other way around: *DENY* access to resources to anyone who isn't bound to a specific Role.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to restrict access on a resource per resource basis.

The RBAC framework works by allowing specified Roles to perform certain actions (`get`, `update`, `delete` etc.) over certain resources (`pods`, `secrets` etc) in a certain namespace.

Clusterroles are used to grant access across all namespaces or to non namespaced resources like nodes.

To achieve what you are looking for you need to isolate your Kubernetes secret in a namespace where you only allow your specific role to read secrets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I accepted the other response because it is a bit more complete, but you said basically the same. Looks like what I'm trying to do is the contrary of how the RBAC was designed.